# JS button prompt with Yes/No options

Tags: javascript, button

Creating a "Remove Token" button that will alert the user with a confirmation "Yes" or "No". Won't work with my current code:

```
<button onclick="alertFunction">Remove Token</button>
  <script>
  function alertFunction() {
  if (confirm('Remove token?')) {
    return;
  } else {
  return false;
  }
  }
  </script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `onclick="alertFunction()"`

Comment: you need the brackets () for function to execute

Comment: Try this as per the comments above https://jsfiddle.net/o5rhtjc1/.

Comment: Mentioning the name of a variable holding a function does nothing. You need to put `()` after it to call it (or use `call()` or `apply()` or similar)

Comment: @jason can I suggest you mark one of the answers below are the 'answer' by clicking the tick next to the answer so the question in marked as resolved

Answer (score 2):

The main problem comes from the missing parentheses `()` in the following line :

```
<button onclick="alertFunction()">Remove Token</button>
______________________________^^
```

I suggest to avoid the inline-event `onclick` and use `addEventListener()` instead :

```js
document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (confirm('Remove token?')) {
    console.log('OK');
  } else {
    console.log('Cancel');
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="my-button">Remove Token</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this has already been mentioned in the comments above. Instead of answering a question where the problem is a typo, vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo -- There's an explicit close reason just for this.

Comment: I've voted to close the question but that doesn't mean not showing the author an example of the best way to go...

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the `()` when you call the function i.e. `onclick="alertFunction()"`

Currently the `onclick` event is just trying to use a variable and not run your function.

Full code:

```
<button onclick="alertFunction()">Remove Token</button>
<script>
  function alertFunction() {
    if (confirm('Remove token?')) {
      return;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Those comments didn't exist when I started writing my solution, I don't see an issue with being helpful if it is a simple error although granted some kind of linting should have been used to spot the typo before posting here. I had also voted to close the question but my reputation doesn't allow the votes to show...

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="alertFunction">Remove Token</button>
```

should be

```
<button onclick="alertFunction()">Remove Token</button>
```

but using Zakaria's approach is likely the more correct one for this type of functionality. Generally speaking its a good habit to keep any functions outside of your markup.

Comment: Yes, this has already been mentioned in the comments above. Instead of answering a question where the problem is a typo, vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo -- There's an explicit close reason just for this.